# Fill text filed with specific register

Tags: jasper-reports

I have a datasource similar to the following:

[image]

How can i fill a textfield in iReport with the specific information from the "NMVALUE" column?

I have tried to fill a field with the following conditional expression without success:

> $F{CDATTRIBUTE} == "590" ? $F{NMVALUE} : "-"

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: What is a type of "CDATTRIBUTE" field?

Comment: It is a INT field type.

Comment: Try this: `$F{CDATTRIBUTE} == 590 ? $F{NMVALUE} : "-"`

Comment: Already did. The result is "-".

Comment: You should post your *jrxml* file. What is your version of JR/iReport?